# filter, arrange and count MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has fields. A user might use and application several times and there is specific applications I want to filter

this table like:

```
username | applicationname
---------------------------
user1      app1
user1      app2
user2      not an app
user2      app1
user3      not an app
user3      app3
user3      app1
user4      app1
user4      app1
```

would become this table

```
user
-----
user1
user3
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Yes, why are user1 and user3 in the results? The only thing they appear to have in common is that they have more than one row.

Comment: yes sorry edited, to be in the result, the must have more than one row with a "valid app" and different ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below using `GROUP BY` clause

```
select `username`
from table1
where applicationname <> 'not an app'
group by username
having count(distinct applicationname) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `having` clause with `case` to check the count of valid `applicationname`:

```
select `user`
from tablename
group by `user`,`applicationname`
having sum(case when `applicationname` <> 'not an app' then 1 end)>1
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your query:

```
SELECT username, publishedapp 
FROM tbl_name 
WHERE publishedapp LIKE "%@%" 
   OR publishedapp LIKE "%Desktop%" 
   OR publishedapp LIKE "%RDP%" 
GROUP BY username,publishedapp
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY username";
```

Comment: Please check edited post, I need applicationname to be specific kind and different applicationnames

Comment: at the moment im "filtering" apps by name, query:
SELECT DISTINCT username, publishedapp
FROM tbl_name
WHERE publishedapp LIKE \"%@%\"
OR publishedapp LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
OR publishedapp LIKE \"%RDP%\"
ORDER BY username";

Comment: @maco1717: See the edit in my answer. And let me know if you need any changes.

Comment: @maco1717: Does your query returns records which do not contain those strings? How does that happen? Do you have more conditions in where clause?

Comment: It was returning record that did not contain thoose strings, had thoose tree conditions above. @rahul given a valid answer.Tx

Comment: @maco1717: No problem, mate.